# Why there's no ambiguity in the expression `d.f(1);` below in main()?

Tags: c++, ambiguous-call, using-declaration

Why there's no ambiguity in the expression `d.f(1);` below in `main()` between `Base::f(int)` and `Derived::f(int)` ?

```
class Base
{
    public:
    void f(int i) {}
    void f(int i, int j) {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    using Base::f;
    void f(int i) {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.f(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have written, there is no ambiguity because `Derived::f(int)` hides `Base::f(int)`. You were probably expecting this to be the case only in the absence of the `using` declaration:

```
using Base::f;
```

But hiding still applies. Paragraph 7.3.3/15 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a derived class scope, **member functions** and
>   member function templates **in the derived class override and/or hide member functions** and member function
>   templates with the same name, *parameter-type-list* (8.3.5), *cv-qualification*, and *ref-qualifier* (if any) in a
>   base class **(rather than conflicting)**.

It also provides an example quite similar to yours (see how the expression `p->f(1)` does not result in ambiguity, and `D::f` is picked instead):

```
struct B {
    virtual void f(int);
    virtual void f(char);
    void g(int);
    void h(int);
};

struct D : B {
    using B::f;
    void f(int); // OK: D::f(int) overrides B::f(int);
    using B::g;
    void g(char); // OK
    using B::h;
    void h(int); // OK: D::h(int) hides B::h(int)
};

void k(D* p)
{
    p->f(1); // calls D::f(int)
    p->f(’a’); // calls B::f(char)
    p->g(1); // calls B::g(int)
    p->g(’a’); // calls D::g(char)
}
```

Comment: +1 Is there any explanation for this, that is, why did they do it this way?

Comment: @user1042389: I can't give you a strong answer on that. In fact, I don't know. I can guess the rationale is, maybe, that the function in the derived class is still considered to be "more specific or more appropriate" than the version in the base class to resolve a call, and therefore it is picked rather than raising an ambiguity. But again, it's just a quick wild guess and you shouldn't take it as anything more than that :)

Answer (score 2):

The function in the derived class hides the function in the base class.
This is called shadowing.

Answer (score 1):

Because the static type of `d` is `Derived`, and `Derived::f(int)` *hides* `Base::f(int)`.